# Proxy in development mode of React won't redirect

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm building an app with `create-react-app`.
I have local `Apache` server running on port 80 to execute my backend API PHP scripts.

I have added 
`"proxy": "http://localhost:80"` to my `package.json`,
but on this `axios` requests:

```
 getAllCategories = () => {
      const url = process.env.PUBLIC_URL+`/api/api/categories/categories.php`; 
      axios.get(url)
        .then(res => {
        const categories = res.data.data;
        this.setState({ categories });
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Axios fetch error:',err);
      })
    }
```

My request are directed to

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api/api/categories/categories.php
```

according to Chrome Devtools and I'm not getting the data required.

In the `build` mode on remote server everything works fine with those paths indicated.

How can I configure proxy in dev mode to access my API files?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tired path like this?

```
axios.get(`/api/api/categories/categories.php`)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `create-react-app` install `http-proxy-middleware`  as a dev dependency and in your `src` folder create a file called `setupProxy.js` (*it must be spelt exactly like that*).

In that file:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy('/api', { target: 'http://localhost:80' }));
};
```

You will need to restart the app for it to take effect.
Your api calls should not need the process.env

Comment: unfortunatelly, just that didn't help, still can't get the data

Comment: in your `url` you have an env variable. If you still have it there it is not going to work, you need to take it out

Comment: removed the `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` from `url` but still can't get the desirable results

Comment: what error are you getting? and why do you have `api/api/~`